# DataGridView decimal value formatting: kosher way

Tags: winforms, datagridview, formatting, decimal

I need to display decimal values in DataGridView

```
        if (dgvClients.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvClients.SelectedRows[0];

            row.Cells["NetAccountValue"].Value = info.DecimalValue;
        }
```

I need to format value up to given digits after decimal separator.

The problem is that cell `Value` property stores reference to decimal in my case. When displayed decimal.ToString() is called and default decimal.ToString() produces unformatted string
with lots of digits.

One way is to create string and use String.FormatString() to achieve desired formatting
and feed it Value instead of decimal.

Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using code you can set the [DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle.aspx).

You can also do this in the designer by:

1. Right clicking your DGV and
   select Edit Columns.  The Edit
   Columns dialog appears.
2. Select your column on the left side
   of the dialog and click the 
   DefaultCellStyle property field to
   bring up the CellStyle Builder.
3. In the Builder dialog click Format
   which brings up the Format String
   Dialog.
4. Make your selections in this dialog
   (select Numeric type, which allows specifying number of decimals to display) and save
   your changes.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution simply.i have searched along two days,found it finally.
-your db column type must be Money or number,double,single.
-Update datagridview event "CellFormatting" as below code.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Aidat")
       {
          string deger=(string)e.Value;
          deger = String.Format("{0:0.00}", deger);
       }
   }
```